# How to redirect url to ssl url on localhost in web.confg

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis, https, web-config

localhost:5011 is url and localhost:44330 is SSL url. I want to redirect http://localhost:5011 to https://localhost:44330 in my web.config. I found rule for this but it is not worked as I wanted:

```
<rule name="Redirect local requests to https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(localhost:5011*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:44330/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

This redirects to https://localhost:5011. How can I fix this?

Comment: Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your rul won't redirect Because<match url= ? doesn't contain hostname and port number.

If you need to redirect  http://localhost:5011 to https://localhost:44330, please try this rule

```
 <rule name="Redirect local requests to https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" />
                        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^5011$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:44330/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

IIs shouldn't redirect  http://localhost:5011 to https://localhost:5011, so please check whether you have other rewrite rule or your application is doing the same work.

Comment: This solution worked with one missing point every request redirected to one page. For example  if request http://localhost:5011/mypage then it redirects to https://localhost:44330.  In order to solve this I added {REQUEST_URI} to Redirect url.